# Google Document Sample with google-api-java-client in Android

Tags: android, google-docs-api, google-api-java-client

I am making a simple apps for Android, This apps have some function:
- Upload
- Download
- ShowAllFile

When i use Gdata, it's easy to make this function in Java

But Gdata didn't support Android.

Can anyone give sample code for GoogleDoc in Android which use google-api-java-clien ?

Best Regards

P/s: UPDATE: i can upload file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Of course G-Data is supported in Android](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android)

On there you will find samples and a video with a presentation on how to access G-Data API on Android

Comment: I use Gdata to upload file without problem. But i cant download, or show all file of my account

Comment: Obviously i cannot see you source code. [But this will help](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/#sample%2Fdocs). If not ask another question with details about why your download failed.

Comment: my method download is ok in java, but when i use it in Android, it's not work!

Comment: As far as I remember GData doesn't work on Android. We have to use googe-api-java-client.

Comment: @Reno - your first link is google-client-api main page, the second - sample with gdata-java-client. Going to gdata main page: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/ - it says: "Looking for a library that supports Android or JSON Google API's? Please instead use Google API Client Library for Java." )

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default. This is a sample for Picasa, but GDoc is much the same.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload (from 1.7)